# Software acknowledgement exposure

Tags: contract-law, software, acknowledgement

I am developing a commercial consumer product and around 90 percent
of the development is software related.

Maybe even more to be completely honest.

Some components of my software uses open source software and with this
comes the responsibility to expose credits of the source of the components
somewhere, in text, that is visible to the users.

This exposure is also called as an "acknowledgement" or "acknowledgement file.

I have a few questions regarding this, mostly about how strict the rules
and laws around this.

First I need to explain where my software is located.

The software I have developed is actually several pieces of softwares for
different platforms.

- iOS app used by iOS users
- Android app used by android users
- Linux application pre-installed on my product

My questions are:

1. Can I collect all of the acknowledgements in to one single file
   and expose it in one common place such as my product website, such as
   inside the the Support page on the website for my product?
2. Do I have to expose each platform-specific acknowledgment file
   inside each and every software?

For example:
The iOS app uses components X, Y and Z.
The Android app uses component A, B and C.
The Linux application uses component I, J, H.

Does the iOS app have to have the acknowledgements of X, Y and Z
and the Android app and Linux application respectively for their components,
or can I put them all in one place?

Comment: Could indicate what licenses these open source components are under?

Comment: Well there are many many different licenses and I haven't gone through them all but it is the common ones, MIT, Mozilla, GPL etc.

Comment: Most likely for those licenses you'll also have to republish the modified source code. For the acknowledgement, just have a copyrights options somewhere in the program that lists all the copyrights used.

Comment: Opensource.SE might be able to give you much more detailed answers. From what I can gather anything you distribute separately needs its separate copyrights description. Most likely you're not distributing android and iOS apps together.

Comment: Oh ok. So basically: If I modify code that is under a certain license I also need to republish the changes of the code. However if I just use the code as-is I only need to acknowledge the original source. Is that correct?

Comment: really depends on the licenses. I think you're correct if you're using libraries under LGPL. Anything under GPLv2 and v3 have to be republished under those licenses. It's quite possible you legally can't use code from two different types of open source licenses. You may want to look into open source compatibility.

Comment: Ok now I'm confused, firstly because this discussion has drifted away about from my original question, secondly because: So I need to republish code even if I in no way what so ever have modified it? Or do you mean that I have to make my software open source just because I am interfacing with open source code?

Comment: I agree this is drifting away from the question. None of what I say is legal advice. Secondly, you have not defined what you mean by interfacing. I suggest you do some research on what you can and cannot do with gpl code. If I remember correctly, linking with or including any gpl code in your project requires your project to be gpl'ed as well. I believe you're fine if you're just interfacing with a gpl program (ie. a wrapper that just invokes another program with proper command line arguments). I'm sure the ppl at opensource would be a lot more helpful.

Comment: Ok, thank you Viktor. I'll see what opensource has to say about this.